# Proof of σ(m) + n = m + σ(n)

Tags: induction, natural-numbers, peano-axioms

Assume $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $\sigma(n)$ be the successor of a $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

**Definition.** Let $+ : \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be a map with the properties:

(1) $n + 0 = n$
(2) $m + \sigma(n) = \sigma(m + n)$

One can show that $0 + n = n$ and $n + 1 = 1 + n = \sigma(n)$.

**Lemma.** $\forall m,n \in \mathbb{N} : \sigma(m) + n = m + \sigma(n)$

Since it is an induction over multiple variables one has to show:

(1) $m=0, n=0$ *(induction basis)*
 (2) $m \rightarrow \sigma(m)$ *(induction step on m)*
 (3) $n \rightarrow \sigma(n)$ *(induction step on n)*

**Base case** ($m=n=0$)

$\sigma(0) + 0 = \sigma(0) = 0 + \sigma(0)\quad\checkmark$

**Induction step** ($n \rightarrow \sigma(n)$)

$\sigma(m) + \sigma(n) = \sigma(\sigma(m) + n) \overset{\text{base case}}{=} \sigma(m + \sigma(n)) = m + \sigma(\sigma(n)) \quad\checkmark$

**Induction step** ($m \rightarrow \sigma(m)$)

$\color{red}{\text{Here I get in trouble.}}$

$\sigma(\sigma(m)) + n ~\overset{?}{=}~ \sigma(m) + \sigma(n)$

I can't apply the definition or the induction basis on $\sigma(\sigma(m))$ when it is on the outer left. And I can't apply commutative or associative law since I need the lemma to proof these theorems.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider the following predicate about  $n\in\Bbb N$:
$$\tag{ $P$}\forall m\colon \sigma(m)+n=m+\sigma(n).$$

As $$m+\sigma(0)\stackrel{(2)}=\sigma(m+0)\stackrel{(1)}=\sigma(m)\stackrel{(1)}=\sigma(m)+0$$ for all $m$, we have shown that $P(0)$ holds.

Let $n\in\Bbb N$ and assume $P(n)$. 
Let $m\in\Bbb N$ be arbitrary.
Then
$$\sigma(m)+\sigma(n)\stackrel{(2)}=\sigma(\sigma(m)+n)\stackrel{P(n)}=\sigma(m+\sigma(n))\stackrel{(2)}=m+\sigma(\sigma(n)).$$
As $m$ was arbitrary, we have shown $P(\sigma(n))$.

As we have shown $P(0)$ and $\forall n\in\Bbb N\colon P(n)\to P(\sigma(n))$, we conclude that $\forall n\in\Bbb N\colon P(n)$, as was to be shown.

Comment: I don't trust the argument that an induction on a predicate with multiple variables can be done by doing the induction over one variable and set the others as arbitrary.

Comment: @ikkowy This is perhaps not clearly worded in the answer, but the predicate is only over $n$, while $m$ is universally quantified inside the predicate.

Comment: Oh okay this sounds meaningful. I should learn more about predicate logic. :D